# .HTACCESS: $_GET variable from URL Friendly htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

In a website I found, they use friendly URLs like this:

**Real URL:**

> example.com/index.php?mode=product

**FRIENDLY URL**

> example.com/view/product.html

In the friendly URL, there is a feature to get a variable with $_GET function. So if the URL looks like this:

**FRIENDLY URL 2**

> example.com/view/product.html?id=10&lang=en&cur=1

This is similar to the friendly URL but allows me to easily access variable parameters.

Can someone help me write an .htaccess rewrite rule like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [QSA] directive in mod_rewrite is your friend here. It will append all the other query string parameters onto the end of the rewritten url:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^view/(.*).html /index.php?mode=$1 [QSA]
```

That is untested, but just a quick answer that should get you going.

Comment: The (.*) might be a little too greedy, but that's the basic idea.